# Get the correspoding values from CSV

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to solve one issue regarding csv. I have read all the values from csv (I have three fields like region,state,acc_name) and loaded into corresponding dropdown list.but my issue is if i select the region i need to get the corresponding state values from csv I have done something but not even get any single line code please help me to do that task.

My code is:

```javascript
$(document).ready(function() {
  // AJAX in the data file
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "data.csv",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
      processData(data);
    }
  });

  // Let's process the data from the data file
  function processData(data) {
    var table = $("<table />");
    var rows = data.split(/\r\n|\n/);
    for (var i = 1; i < rows.length - 1; i++) {
      var row = $("<tr />");
      var cells = rows[i].split(/,(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*(?![^\"]*\"))/);

      for (var j = 0; j < rows.length; j++) {
        var cell = $("<td />");
        cell.html(cells[j]);
        row.append(cell);
      }

      var usedNames = {};
      $("select[name='company1'] > option").each(function() {
        if (usedNames[this.text]) {

          $(this).remove();
        } else {
          usedNames[this.text] = this.value;
        }
      });
      $("select[name='company2'] > option").each(function() {
        if (usedNames[this.text]) {

          $(this).remove();
        } else {
          usedNames[this.text] = this.value;
        }
      });
      $("select[name='company3'] > option").each(function() {
        if (usedNames[this.text]) {

          $(this).remove();
        } else {
          usedNames[this.text] = this.value;
        }
      });

      var newvalue = cells[1].replace("\"", "");
      //var newvalue=cells[1].trim();

      var final1 = newvalue.replace("\"", "");

      var pandu = cells[0];
      $("#region").append("<option value =" + cells[0] + "> " + cells[0] + " </option>");
      $("#state").append("<option value =" + final1 + "> " + final1 + "</option>");
      $("#accname").append("<option value =" + cells[2] + ">" + cells[2] + "</option>");

      table.append(row);
    }

  }
});
```

```javascript
function getstate() 
{
...
}
```

HTML:

```html
Region:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<select id="region" class="select" name="company1" onchange="getstate()"></select>
<br> State: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<select id="accname" class="select" name="company3"></select>
<br> Acct_Name:
<select id="state" class="select" name="company2"></select>
<br>
```